# Unexpected token m in JSON at position 4 - passing string from spring controller to angular controller

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

Facing error when trying to send the string from spring controller to angular controller, 
spring controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/getProductData", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/plain")
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String getDetails() throws Exception {

    //logic
    String productNames = "product1,prod2,prod3,prod4";

    return productNames;
}
```

angularjs controller:

```
myApp.controller('getProductDataController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'MyService', function ($rootScope, $scope, MyService) {

  MyService.getProductDetails().then(
  function(response){

  $scope.productDetails = response;

  });

  }



Error : angular.min.js?dummy=0.5032774462756217:119 SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 4
    at JSON.parse
```

Comment: Check what is passed on the network, that exception tells that it is not a json.

Comment: If you are sending the literal string  `product1,prod2,prod3,prod4`, that is not valid JSON and this error is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

This part: `produces = "text/plain"` looks like you're telling Spring to return the value `"product1,prod2,prod3,prod4"` as a **string**.

Angular is going to try parse that as JSON. Open your Dev Tools and run this code:

`JSON.parse('product1,product2')`

You'll see it can't parse a string into JSON.

Try using: `produces = "application/json"`

Comment: (Not sure where the 'm' comes from, though, as that's not in your string)